# Load javascripts inside jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have several javascripts at the head of my document, as well as at the bottom, near the `body` closing tag. I use jQuery to call an ajax element into place and the elements that are called, require these javascripts to function. How can I include these javascripts to work with the ajax call?

Example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 

        jQuery("a[rel=VideoPreview1]").click(function(){
            jQuery("a[rel=VideoPreview1]").hide();
            jQuery("a[rel=HideVideoPreview1]").show();
            jQuery.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "/Classes/Video.php",
               data: "action=getYoutubeVideos&artist=B.o.B&track=Nothin On You",
              success: function(data){
                 jQuery("#VideoPreview1").html(data);
               }
             });
            jQuery("#VideoPreview1").show();
        preventDefault();
        });
        jQuery("a[rel=HideVideoPreview1]").click(function(){
            jQuery("a[rel=VideoPreview1]").show();
            jQuery("a[rel=HideVideoPreview1]").hide();
            jQuery("#VideoPreview1").hide();
            preventDefault();
        });
        });
```

So that ajax function loads the content inside of the proper DIV element. The head contains the core files (i.e. jquery, tooltip, lightbox) and near the bottom of the code, the javascripts are referenced (i.e. load.tooltip(VideoPreview1))

Hope this is enough information now

Comment: How are you getting the replacement elements? what jQuery function?

Comment: can you provide an example or more specifics?

Comment: See my edit for more information

Comment: ok so problem appears to be with re initiating functions. For example, if I use getScript OR include the script file in the ajax file that gets called, it doesn't work AND breaks my elements using the same functions outside of the ajax element. It doesn't matter if the javascript is in header or at bottom, either way ajax doesn't recognize something like this:

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
     jQuery('a[title]').qtip({
      style: { name: 'dark', tip: true },
   position: {
   target: ('mouse'),
            corner: {
               tooltip: 'topLeft', // ...and position it center of the screen
               target: 'bottomRight' // ...and position it center of the screen
            }
         }
  });
  jQuery('img').removeAttr('alt');
 });
</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is what I ended up doing:

```
<script>
   function BottomVideoPlayer(){
      // MY JAVASCRIPT HERE
   }
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      init: BottomVideoPlayer();
   });

</script>
```

And then when I want to call it into Ajax:

```
<script>
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/Classes/Video.php",
      data: "action=getYoutubeVideos&artist='.$Artist.'&track='.$Track.'",
      success: function(data){                      
      jQuery("#VideoPreview'.$SongID.'").html(data);
      init: BottomVideoPlayer();
      }
     });
</script>
```

Just wrapped my script around a function and initiate the function whenever I need it.